# how can i query user data by email in FQL?

Tags: php, facebook

how can i query user's uid by email in FQL?

for example: my account email is 'mingfish@qq.com',

I want to query my facebook data using fql like this:

```
// not works
select uid from user where email = 'mingfish@qq.com'
// or
select uid from user where email = mingfish@qq.com


// can not post
// can not post
// can not post
// can not post
// can not post
// can not post
// can not post
```

or any other way to check whether this user exists? I only want to know whether the user is a real facebook user who register this in my site.

Comment: a basic understanding of SQL would tell you eactly why your second option would never ever work.

Comment: You can’t do that, since `email` is not an indexable field in the `user` table. If a user registers to your site with Facebook, you have their FB user id, so you can use that to look up their user details using FQL or the Graph API.